# Is there a better way to create a Fusion Table from a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I was overjoyed to see Fusion Tables added as a service to Google Apps Script and I've started experimenting with it. But so far the only way I've successfully been able to create a table is with the following code. But it it seems over complicated to me. Is there a better way to do it?!

```
function createTable() {
  var newTbl = FusionTables.newTable();
  newTbl.name = 'TEST_Test';
  newTbl.isExportable = false;
  var newCol1 = FusionTables.newColumn();
  newCol1.name = 'Symbol';
  newCol1.type = 'STRING';
  var newCol2 = FusionTables.newColumn();
  newCol2.name = 'Name';
  newCol2.type = 'STRING';
  newTbl.columns = [newCol1, newCol2];
  var theTable = FusionTables.Table.insert(newTbl);
  Logger.log('Table with ID "%s" was created.', theTable.tableId);
}
```

I just didn't think I'd need to create so many variables. I was expecting to inline much more of those steps by providing inline objects or chaining objects or something.

On a side note, the documentation for [Fusion Tables Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables) could really use some expansion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an alternate, here's what I would do if my code was going to create the same table multiple times.  I would define a JSON resource string of the table columns collection as defined here.  Add a line to load the resource string and a call to parse to create the collection.
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/column

I'm not sure which would execute faster, I haven't run any tests.